# Grails GSP and template relations

Tags: javascript, css, templates, grails

When you have a GSP and then say you try to render a template into some part of it, if the template is sophisticated enough that it has to have its own CSS and JS, where is the best place to put the template's css and js? I currently have it inline with the template's markup in the same file such as but I feel it belongs with the parent GSP's css and js like maybe in the same files? Suggestions?

So right now the parent GSP looks like this.

```
<head>
  reference to external file which has the parent GSP's css
  inline JS
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
```

and the template which I render later into that GSP looks like this:

```
inline CSS
inline JS
inline markup
```

I know this isn't the cleanest, best strategy therefore I seek input as to what is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "*It depends*". It depends on how you are using the template.

More specifically are you reusing the template? If so, then it makes more sense to put the required CSS and JS within the template itself so it's self contained and reusable in such a manner.

If you are simply using the template for partial rendering then, and only within a specific parent GSP then it makes more sense to include the CSS and JS within the parent GSP and not the template.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this kind of scenario are using plugins like [Grails Resource plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/) or [Grails Asset Pipeline Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline), both of them provide ways to keep organisation in yours resources (css, JavaScript) files

For example using grails resource plugin you could create a module that include specific view resource and template resource as a dependency all this possible using this plugin and keep it clean.

You can find useful information about resource plugin in this [Marc Palmer Post](http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2011/09/12/optimising-your-application-with-grails-resources-plugin/)
About asset pipline plugin in this [Bobby Warner Post](http://www.bobbywarner.com/2014/02/26/grails-asset-pipeline-plugin/)

I hope this help